# st_length column in Postgres db and ArcGIS under WGS84

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, wgs84

I have a polyline feature class in ArcGIS running on top of postgres in WGS84 datum. I am wondering what is the unit of length used to drive st_length column under this datum and what is the method of calculation. I am getting this feeling that it is a blind function only useful if the data is in a projected format.

In projected coordinate systems, it is in meters.

Comment: It is using the units of the coordinate system. In this case degrees. You are right, those measures do not make sense. Cast geometry into geography or transform into projected system first.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: If it is PostGIS that populates that length column, the PostGIS doc is the place to look. Second sentance: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Length.html

Comment: I am not sure if PostGIS populates it or ArcGIS. Note that although this function does exist in PostGIS, one needs to add ArcGIS libraries to postgre libs folder for ArcGIS to work and hence it might be different. I am looking for documentation on this. I also know that `st_length(shape)` always returns length in meters for projected coordinate systems.

Answer (score 1):

Measurement functions on `geometry` types do basic calculations in Cartesian space, where the output units are the same as the input distance units. This is well understood and documented (see [ST_Length](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Length.html)).

WGS84 uses degrees, so ST_Length and ST_Area have outputs in degrees and degrees². However for most practical purposes, these units do not make sense.

You can convert `geometry` types using WGS84 into `geography` types to use similar functions ST_Length and ST_Area to calculate more meaningful calculations, where the units are in m and m².

For example, compare the three distances. The last two use geography, but compare calculations using geodesics on a spheroid (or an ellipsoid of revolution) versus calculations on a sphere.

```
SELECT
  ST_Length(g) AS geom_length,
  ST_Length(g::geography) AS spheroid_length,
  ST_Length(g::geography, false) AS sphere_length
FROM (SELECT 'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(0 20, 10 30)'::geometry AS g) AS s;

   geom_length   | spheroid_length  |  sphere_length
-----------------+------------------+------------------
 14.142135623731 | 1497148.92411447 | 1499101.28894191
```